# Skimage: how to combine RGB channels?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have three grey channels of one image, each channel is a 2-dim array with values from 0 to 255. I need to combine this three images to one RGB and get something like this: [[234, 45, 67], ...], ... [[34, 7, 162], ...]! I use skimage, numpy to solve this problem. I can't find in documentation appropriate function(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use numpy's dstack (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)

```
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(10)
g = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)

zipped = np.dstack((r, g, b))
```